# Why am I getting an Index error when I do this If statement and a[i]

Tags: python

Issue is with an if statement and a for loop

It's supposed to find the highest number in the list and find how many there are of it

```
L = []
n = 6
a = [5, 1, 4, 88, 6, 7, 4, 88, 6, 6, 88, 5, 3, 45, 57]

b = max(a)

for i in a:
    if a[i] == b:
        L.append(a[i])
print(L)
```

error says "list index out of range"

Comment: i changed the True btw that isn't there anymore

Comment: `i` is not the index, it's the actual value. So you can just use `i` and not `a[i]`. Alternatively, use `for i in range(len(a)):`.

Comment: `for i in a:` loops over the *values* in the list, NOT the indexes.  The fourth value assigned to `i` will be 88, which is not a valid index for a 15-element list.

Comment: _"i changed the True btw that isn't there anymore"_ then [edit] your question to remove it

Comment: ty, i got it to work if i set the len(a) to another variable and replace that with a

Comment: sorry didnt know you could edit it

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over an array, you get the values, not the indices. So consider

```
for element in a:
    if element == b == True:
        L.append(element)
```

Also, do keep in mind that capital names are generally reserved for `CONSTANTS` and `ClassNames` in Python, so your use of `L` as an array variable is not terribly Pythonic. Consider a more descriptive name, like `result_list` or `largest_elements`.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments, `i` is not the index, it is the element in `a` as you are traversing `a`.

If you need the index, use this:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
```

or you can do:

```
for i in a:
    if i == b:
        L.append(i)
```

Comment: And the second approach is what all the good Python programmers do.